# jquery game runs slowly on mobile phone

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am coding a simple game recently, it runs normally on PC, but it runs slowly on mobile phone. I am just wondering whether the problem is caused by my code or by jquery.
Should I use jquery while writing game for mobile phone

here is the demo:[my game demo link](http://acm.gdufe.edu.cn/bbb)

js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var min = 0;
    var max = 3;
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var rowHeight = windowHeight / 4 - 1;
    var colWidth = windowWidth / 4 - 1;
    var totalTime = 30;
    var score = 0;

    function layout() {
        $('.row').height(rowHeight);
        $('.col').width(colWidth);
    }

    function init () {
        layout();
        $('.row').each(function () {
            //var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min); // return random number between min and max;
            var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
            $(this).children().eq(rand).addClass('active');
        });

        $('#time').text(totalTime);
    }

    function insertNewRow () {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
        var newRowStr = '<div class="row">';
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            newRowStr += '<div class="col"></div>';
        }
        newRowStr += '</div>';
        var $newRow = $(newRowStr);
        $newRow.height(rowHeight).children().width(colWidth).eq(rand).addClass('active');
        $newRow.prependTo('#wrapper');
    }

    function removeLastRow () {
        $('.row:last').remove();
    }


    var counting;
    function startCountDown () {
        counting = setInterval(countDown, 1000);
    }

    function countDown() {
        var timeLeft = $('#time').text();
        timeLeft -= 1;
        $('#time').text(timeLeft);

        if (timeLeft == 0) {
            gameover();
        }
    }

    function gameover () {
        clearInterval(counting);
        $('#end').show().find('#score').text("your score：" + score);
    }

    function restartGame () {
        score = 0;
        $('#time').text(totalTime);
        startCountDown();
    }

    init();

    $('#wrapper').on('click', '.row:eq(3) .active', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        score++;
        $(this).removeClass('active').addClass('clicked').parent().remove();
        //setTimeout(removeLastRow, 200);
        insertNewRow();
    }); 

    $('#launch').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#start').hide();
        startCountDown();
    });

    $('#retry').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#end').hide();
        restartGame();
    });
});
```

html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="files/style.css">
    <script src="files/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="files/game.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="start">
        <a id="launch" href="#">START</a>
    </div>
    <div id="time"></div>
    <div id="end">
        <h1 id="score"></h1>
        <a id="retry" href="#">AGAIN</a>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col"></div>
            <div class="col"></div>
            <div class="col"></div>
            <div class="col"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col"></div>
            <div class="col"></div>
            <div class="col"></div>
            <div class="col"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col"></div>
            <div class="col"></div>
            <div class="col"></div>
            <div class="col"></div> 
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col"></div>
            <div class="col"></div>
            <div class="col"></div>
            <div class="col"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which operating system? And define "slowly".

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: I tried your game and I don't really understand the concept, however that aside the game itself shouldn't be "slow" on mobile phone because there isn't really an "animation" going on, nor do you have a significant number of lines of code that can make it lag. When you say slow, what is slow?

Comment: You use id selectors, which are very fast, so jQuery shouldn't be the problem. You could keep the references to the DOM elements/jQuery elements. You still need to define what *slow* means for you.

Comment: my 'slow' is: if I am using Meizu MX3 to play this game, it's good, but when I used XiaoMi S2 to play it, it runs slowly. I click the block and I have to wait for a few time(less than 0.5s, but it looks slowly on the mobile phone), before it generate next row of blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general jQuery is very slow, which one rarely experiences since we have such fast computers. But you seem to use jQuery for almost every interaction here. You might consider make some improvements to that. Check out this nice article about the issue.

[jQuery Newbs: Stop Jumping in the Pool](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-jquery-newbs-stop-jumping-in-the-pool--net-22142)